# Why is my docker networks gateway IP unaccessible from my host OS

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to get the following set up working:

- My local machine OS = Linux
- I am building a docker mysql container on this local machine
- I plan to seed the database within the container, and then run tests locally (on my local Linux machine) against this container (which i will spin up on my linux machine too)

Unfortunately when running my tests and trying to connect to the container, the default `bridge` networks Gateway IP is inaccessible.

My `docker-compose.yaml` file is as follows

```yml
version: "3.4"

services:
  integration-test-mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: ${MY_SQL_CONTAINER_NAME}
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      # - ./src/db:/usr/src/db #Mount db folder so we can run seed files etc.
      - ./seed.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/seed.sql
    network_mode: bridge
    healthcheck:
      test: "mysqladmin -u root -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -h 127.0.0.1 ping --silent 2> /dev/null || exit 1" 
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 10s 
    entrypoint: sh -c "
      echo 'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS gigs;' > /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql;
      /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
      "
```

When running `docker network ls` i see the following

```bash
 docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME                  DRIVER    SCOPE
42a11ef835dd   bridge                bridge    local
c7453acfbc98   host                  host      local
48572c69755a   integration_default   bridge    local
bd470f8620fd   none                  null      local
```

So the `integration_default` network was created. Then if i inspect this network

```bash
docker network inspect integration_default
[
    {
        "Name": "integration_default",
        "Id": "48572c69755ae1bbc1448ab203a01d81be4300da12c97a9c4f1142872b878387",
        "Created": "2022-09-28T00:48:20.504251612Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.27.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.27.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "79e897decb4f0ae5836c018d82e78997e8ac2f615b399362a307cc7f585c0875": {
                "Name": "integration-test-mysql-host",
                "EndpointID": "1f7798554029cc2d07f7ba44d057c489b678eac918f7916029798b42585eda41",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:1b:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.27.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "integration",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.7.0"
        }
    }
]
```

Comparing this to the default bridge

```bash
docker inspect bridge

[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "42a11ef835dd1b2aec3ecea57211bb2753e0ebd4a2a115ace8b7df3075e97d5a",
        "Created": "2022-09-27T21:54:44.239215269Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Interestingly running `ping  172.17.0.1` on my Linux machine works fine but `ping 172.27.0.1` fails to return anything

**UPDATE**
I have got it working now. By specifying `network_mode: bridge` in my docker compose file i was able to use the default bridge network which was accessible on my local machine as i mentioned.

However, i would like to know why creating my own network didn't work here. Does anyone know why this was the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker networks are meant to be hidden and you should let docker do its job unless there is a good reason for it.

The correct way to interract with a service is through its open ports. And those ports are mapped on the host so that talking to the host:port is like talking to the app inside the container.

So when you say that you can't ping your container from the host, it is because Docker does its job good. "Fixing" this breaks the isolation of the container and makes it available to other services that shouldn't have acccess to it.

Comment: yes ok. I understand that to expose a port in your container on the container host, you need to map the container post to your host port, which i have done in my composer yaml file. So from my understanding i should be able to interact with my container (by a ping for example) as long as i do so via an exposed port. I also tried `telnet 172.27.0.1 3306` to hit the exposed port, but i have no real networking experience so maybe im doing something wrong there and this port doesn't accept HTTP requests or something

Comment: also note that both the networks tested were bridge networks. The default docker one allowed me to ping the container host via the gateway ip, but the one i created didn't. I understand your point but why is the behaviour different here? Clearly it is possible to interact with the container via my Linux machine which is running the docker daemon. Surely there are lots of cases where you might want to interact with a docker container from outside its network too? Mine is an example

Comment: you expose the port on host. docker makes sure that what you send to the exposed port gets to the right container on the right port. you have to forget about container IP's. `telnet localhost 3306` is what you are looking for

Comment: ah ok thanks, i was getting confused. I was thinking there was a layer between my local machine and the docker 'host'. Now i understand they are the same thing